# Compare User Defined Variable to Jmeter Variable Response

Tags: jmeter

I have a question about user defined variable that I want to compare to field in Response:

1. I created `Json Extractor` and put the value from the response that I need to check in a variable called `CID`.
2. I have a user defined variable in the start of the test called `Expected_CID`
3. I Added response Assertion
   In the response assertion I could find out how to compare `CID` to `Expected_CID`
   If I put the number it is working as expected but I want to use variable and not hard coded numbers.

Can someone please explain what I do wrong?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names are case sensitive.

So for example , if you called CID, then cid won't match.

So in Response Assertion:

- JMeter Variable : CID
- In Patterns to test, use ${Expected_CID}

Answer (score 1):

To check variable in `Response Assertion` you need to put variable name inside ${}, this way JMeter will know you want to check your variable value.

In your case use `${Expected_CID}` in `Patterns to Test` Text area, If not working make sure you don't have extra spaces in its `User Defined Variables` Value.

Notice in `Response Assertion`'s `Jmeter Variable` you don't need to put variable name inside ${}, because it's expected for find variable.

A @UBIK LOAD PACK mention, notice that:

> Variable names are case sensitive

.